# LINQ expression inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, for-loop, asp.net-mvc-5

In my View() i have many checkboxes with attr name="types". In my ActionResult I have a List types like parameter, and I do foreach loop to search in List, each type ID and add a Where() filter in my LINQ expression. If I select many types, the return is only one result and dont all what i chose. Look:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<int> types) {
  var variable = from s in MyViewModel select s;

  foreach(var type in types) {
    variable = variable.Where(x => x.TypesId == type);
  }

  return View(MyViewModel);
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: So you're looking for Type == 1 OR Type == 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
variable = variable.Where(x => types.Contains(x.TypesId));
```

This should give you all the values, if you only want one, add `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems in your code, no matter what other part of code do your return statement always returns all `MyViewModel` collection.

Other problem is your code overwrite `variable` inside the loop.

I think, this is what you need.

```
return View(MyViewModel.Select(s=> types.Any(t=>t.type == s.TypesId));
```

Comment: @FabricioOliveria did you try this approach?

Answer (score 0):

make attr name from  name="types" to  name="types[]"

and it will post array of selected values

Answer (score 0):

The `variable` is being reset each `foreach` iteration. Create a `List` and add to it in `foreach` block.